# How to join multiple fields in order using mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a table where it has Size and Price for each product. There could be multiple sizes with prices. I want to read size and price with ":" separated while each size:price is separated by commas for each product.

If I read it using SQL query I get the following.

```
PRODUCT_ID     SIZE     PRICE
001            L        20 
001            S        15
002            M        10
002            L        20
002            S        5
```

I want to read the following as follows :

```
PRODUCT        SIZE_PRICE
001            L:20,S:15
002            M:10,L:20,S:5
```

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Why did you just delete your other question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `group_concat` with `CONCAT`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   PRODUCT_ID varchar(50),
   SIZE varchar(50),
   PRICE int
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('001','L',20); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('001','S',15);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('002','M',10);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('002','L',20);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('002','S',5);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
      GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(SIZE,':',PRICE)) 'SIZE_PRICE'
FROM T
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID;

| PRODUCT_ID | SIZE_PRICE    |
| ---------- | ------------- |
| 001        | L:20,S:15     |
| 002        | M:10,L:20,S:5 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bbYaEZ5xy61iuNT9Bw1K7u/0)

Comment: . . You don't need `CONCAT()`.  Just use `GROUP_CONCAT( SIZE, ':', PRICE)`.  `GROUP_CONCAT()` takes multiple arguments.